# why Django put application at the same level of my project folder?

Tags: django, directory-structure

since Django 1.4 (I think) django create a folder for my project when I start a project. Django add a folder for any application I created (with **python manage.py startapp**) at the same level of my project folder.

```
Project_name
   |---project_name_dir/
   |---application_dir/
   `---manage.py
```

I really like the following folder structure:

```
Project_name
   |---project_name_dir/
   |      |---application_dir/
   |      |       |-- __init__.py
   |      |       |-- models.py
   |      |       |-- tests.py
   |      |       `-- views.py
   |      |-- __init__.py
   |      |-- settings.py
   |      |-- urls.py 
   |      |-- wsgi.py
   |      |---templates/
   |      |      `---application_dir/
   |      `---static/
   |            |---css/
   |            |---font/
   |            |---img/
   |            `---js/
   |---deployment/
   |---documentation/
   |---config/
   `---manage.py
```

Because I have a folder with all my django files (project_name_dir/) and other directories for non django files.

**So why Django put application at the same level of my project folder?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django, the position of the application directory is not considered. Django only uses the name of the application.

Thus, the position of the application is basically a matter of convenience of the programmer.

This is also the reason why two apps should not have the same name: even if they are imported in `INSTALLED_APPS` as

```
('app.app1', 'app1')
```

Django only concerns with the last part after the dot, i.e. `app1`.

So, in the end, you can use the directory structure you want, as long as the apps' names don't collide and you point to the app on `INSTALLED_APPS`. Because of this, if there isn't any special reason, you should put them on the project's root, like Django does.

Comment: If the position application is a matter of convenience of the programmer, I still do not understand why Django change manage.py features. It feels more complicated than in 1.3.